# JavaScript split time in chunks

Tags: javascript, datetime

How could I split time every X minutes, if I know the start time and end time. So for instance, if my start time is `13:00` and my end time is: `15:00` and splitting it every 30 minutes, then I would like to get an array containing:

```
13:00 - 13:30
14:00 - 14:30
14:30 - 15:00
```

Comment: what variable type are your times stored in? Strings?

Comment: What should the output array contain? Those strings, literally? Or pairs of `Date` objects? Something else?

Comment: either way... preferably the Date Object

Answer (score 1):

You can use [datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs) and its [add](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#add) method to add minutes to your Date object. The [compareTo](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#compareTo) method can be used to check that you are still within the appropriate range.

If you don't want to use an external library, you can refer to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp).

```
//Set minutes
var myDate=new Date();
myDate.setMinutes(myDate.getMinutes()+30);

//Compare two dates.
var x=new Date();
x.setFullYear(2100,0,14);
var today = new Date();
if (x>today)
  {
  alert("Today is before 14th January 2100");
  }
else
  {
  alert("Today is after 14th January 2100");
  }
```

Comment: @Mike datejs is MIT so you can just look at the code and do what they do.

Answer (score 1):

```
13:00 - 13:30
13:30 - 14:00
14:00 - 14:30
14:30 - 15:00
```

[see it in action](http://jsbin.com/arelir/22)

```
var makeTimeIntervals = function (startTime, endTime, increment) {
    startTime = startTime.toString().split(':');
    endTime = endTime.toString().split(':');
    increment = parseInt(increment, 10);

    var pad = function (n) { return (n < 10) ? '0' + n.toString() : n; },
        startHr = parseInt(startTime[0], 10),
        startMin = parseInt(startTime[1], 10),
        endHr = parseInt(endTime[0], 10),
        endMin = parseInt(endTime[1], 10),
        currentHr = startHr,
        currentMin = startMin,
        previous = currentHr + ':' + pad(currentMin),
        current = '',
        r = [];

    do {
        currentMin += increment;
        if ((currentMin % 60) === 0 || currentMin > 60) {
            currentMin = (currentMin === 60) ? 0 : currentMin - 60;
            currentHr += 1;
        }
        current = currentHr + ':' + pad(currentMin);
        r.push(previous + ' - ' + current);
        previous = current;
  } while (currentHr !== endHr);

    return r;
};

var a = makeTimeIntervals('13:00', '15:00', 30);

for (var i in a) if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) { document.body.innerHTML += a[i] + '<br />'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

well that wrecks everything :P ... oh well ... for this who want to do this for strings:

```
function getIntervals(startString,endString,intervalString) {
var start = startString.split(":");
var end = endString.split(":");
var interval = intervalString.split(":");
startInMinutes = start[0]*60+start[1]*1;
endInMinutes = end[0]*60+end[1]*1;
intervalInMinutes = interval[0]*60+interval[1]*1;
var times = [];
var intervalsOfTime = [];

for(var i = startInMinutes; i <= endInMinutes; i+=intervalInMinutes) {
  var hour = Math.floor(i/60) + "";
  var minute = i%60 + "";
  minute = (minute.length < 2) ? "0" + minute : minute;
  hour = (hour.length < 2) ? "0" + hour : hour;
  times.push( hour + ":" + minute);
}


for(var i = 0; i < times.length-1; i++)
  intervalsOfTime.push(times[i] + " - " + times[i+1])

return intervalsOfTime;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### I know I'm late in answering this, but I'm posting my solution for anybody who's still stuck.

Using moment.js:-

```
const moment = require('moment');

// Actual logic

const splitTime = (startTime, endTime, interval) =>{
    const result = [startTime.toString()];
    let time = startTime.add(interval,'m');
    while(time.isBetween(startTime,endTime,undefined,[])){
        result.push(time.toString());
        time = time.add(interval,'m');
    }
    return result;
}


// You change these values according to your needs

const interval = 60;
const startTime = new moment({hour:00,minute:00});
const endTime = new moment({hour:12, minute:00});

const timeSlices = splitTime(startTime,endTime,interval); 

// For printing out the intervals 

for(let i=0;i<timeSlices.length-1;i++){
    console.log(timeSlices[i]+" - "+timeSlices[i+1]);
}
```

Hope this was a straightforward answer and has helped you, reader. :)